# Get Employee Name from another table, by employee ID from input field in form

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an access database that i have gracefully been deemed responsible for.. I for the life of me cannot figure out how to do this simple relationship scenario..

### Call Table

```
id - PKey Auto Inc
job_number
employee_id - Text -> links to UserInfo Linked SharePoint List Table
call_description
```

### User Info Linked SharePoint Table

This table is readonly, a linked table from a SharePoint list..

```
id - PKey Auto Inc
employee_id
Name - Full name of employee
```

On the input form the call center tech will fill the form out, and enter the employee's ID number. Once they enter that i want it to show the employees name from the `[UserInfo].[Name]`  column in a textbox..

I tried using a `DLookup` function like so:

```
=DLookUp("[Name]","[UserInfo]"," [UserInfo]![Employee ID] =" & [Forms]![Call Entry]![employee_number])
```

but all i'm getting is #Error. the form's data source is set to the Call Table.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a combobox so they when they type in their employee number the name is also right there.

Comment: becuase i dont want to store the name, i only want to store their id # :)

Comment: You won't *be* storing the name. The combo box will pull it into the form, but only the ID will be stored.

Comment: then provide the answer on how to do it..

Comment: Why don't you fire some little vbscript on the on-change event? At least back in 2001 or so that worked.

Comment: Thats definitely one solution, ill dig into some vb options..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the CompanyName field from table Company, where **CompanyID** = 874. This translates to:

```
=DLookup("CompanyName", "Company", "CompanyID = 874")
```

You don't want Company 874 printed for every record! Use an ampersand (`&`) to concatenate the current value in the **CompanyID** field of your report to the "Company = " criteria:

```
=DLookup("CompanyName", "Company", "CompanyID = " & [CompanyID])
```

If the **CompanyID** is null (as it might be at a new record), the 3rd agumenent will be incomplete, so the entire expression yields #Error. To avoid that use `Nz()` to supply a value for when the field is null:

```
=DLookup("CompanyName", "Company", "CompanyID = " & Nz([CompanyID],0))
```